# How to launch an external program (process) as a different user from .net

Tags: c#, .net, process

In my .net web application, I need to launch another program as a new process - under a different user account (one with higher priviledges). My code runs without error, but I never get any output (I've tried Redirecting the output), and the program doesn't seem to execute at all. Its not an error with the User auth details, I've tried a bogus username and sure enough it throws a valid exception in that case. Nothing gets added to the event log.

```
 SecureString passwordString = new SecureString();
 foreach (char c in "MyPassword")
 {
     passwordString.AppendChar(c);
 }

var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        UserName = "myuser", Password = passwordString, Domain = "MyDomain",
        WorkingDirectory = HttpContext.Request.MapPath("~/bin"),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = HttpContext.Request.MapPath("~/bin") + "\\ServerCertificateImporter.exe",
        Arguments = instanceLocationId.ToString(),
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        RedirectStandardError = false
    }
};

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Comment: in some circumstances newer Windows versions will block communication between 2 processes with different levels of privileges... don't do this in a web application... you can get it to work but only by adding some security risks...

Comment: This is win 7 / win server 2008...

Comment: then what I wrote is what is happening to you - the security model has been modified+extended by MS starting with Vista...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yahia pointed out, this was caused by the fact that I was trying to call a program with a different user account - and windows didn't want me to do that.